# Why can't I use ' instead of " for JSON string?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a very basic json string, to my surprise I got this error :

> Json unexpected token at position 1

https://jsfiddle.net/5L2sgr57/

```
  var jsonString = "{'name': 'john'}";
  JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

It works if I switch ' with " but for what reason would I need to do so since in javascript string ' and " are supposedly equivalent ?

Comment: `Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.` seen here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ with your json-text...

Comment: Just because [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is **not Javascript**. It is a language-independent data format with specific syntax.

Comment: C# doesn't allow using `'` instead of `"` so that's why... #samelogic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch your single and double quotation marks

```
var jsonString = '{"name": "john"}';
JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

### JSON is not equal to Javascript

> JSON is a text format that is completely language independent but uses conventions that are familiar to programmers of the C-family of languages, including C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, Perl, Python, and many others. These properties make JSON an ideal data-interchange language. (www.json.org)

You can verify the allowed JSON syntax [here](http://www.json.org/)

In the syntax-definition for a string, you can see that `'`is not allowed.

[image]

Comment: @user310291 well you changed the whole meaning of the question actually lol

Comment: @user310291 Because the parser expects a `"`, not a `'`, that's it. Anyway, it could expect a `'`, but this is the way it has been done

Comment: @user310291 yes I know now that that was what you meant. Wasn't clear from the initial question. Anyway, I provided the explanation now ;-)

Comment: Ah ok will mark your answer as right answer :) still this isn't logical since javascript string accepts both.

Comment: @user310291 thanks, but it is actually logical. It is not javascript, it's json, a different 'language' if you will :-)

Comment: all right also Json is not just used for Javascript.

Comment: @user310291 indeed, far from :-)